# How to fade in/out a single image from a list of images with jQuery

Tags: jquery, animation, fadein, imagelist

I am almost sorry about asking here, as I believe its going to be a simple quest, but I cant figure out how to build this with jQuery as I am still learning.

We are trying to clean up a badly coded website with javascript animations going here and there, so I want to simplify the development by turning every part into jQuery instead of DHTML/Javascript hacks that is a mess to maintain.

**Situation**

I have two DIVs one for the "shown image" called

```
<div id="fader"></div> /* the shown object */
```

Then somewhere in the HTML I have a user defined list of images to show in that fader container.

The images are in a container I've called

```
        <div id="fadercontent"></div>
```

Like this:

```
        <div id="fadercontent">
                <div><img src="image0101.jpg" width="200" height="200" border="0" alt="" /></div>
                <div><img src="image0444.jpg" width="200" height="200" border="0" alt="" /></div>
                <div><img src="image0256.jpg" width="200" height="200" border="0" alt="" /></div>
                <div><img src="image6821.jpg" width="200" height="200" border="0" alt="" /></div>
        </div>
```

This list can vary in size, some has 1 image, some has 20... 
Reason for DIV is that I might change it from IMG to something else some day. So I want to grab the DIV + all content and fade this "DIV" into the "fader" object.

**Solution/idea**

I was trying to collect them in an array first. By grabbing the list from fadercontent DIVs.

Something like:

```
var fadercontent = $('#fadercontent').children();
```

Then I would take the first item from fadercontent and replace the content of "#fader"

I've figured out that $("#fader").html(...) is how I replace the contents and fadeIn() would be the opacity fader.

**What I can't figure out is:**

1) how do I keep track of which item is next, eg. find the next in the fadercontent object, so that I can loop the list. In javascript I used the array length and a simple counter.

2) how do I set animation speed. Trying to build fadeIn through 2 sec, then pause 1 sec, then 2 sec fadeout, replace image,  2 sec fadeIn (loop). jQuery.Animate needed perhaps?

Hoping someone with jQuery talent will show me what I need to go further here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below will loop through each child of `faderContent` and replace the html of `fader`... and it will just keep going and start from the beginning when it reaches the end

```
var index = -1;
var max = $("#fadercontent").children().length;
FadeNext();

function FadeNext() {
    index++;
    // check if at the end, otherwise start over
    if (index >= max) index = 0;

    // if #fader has no children, fadeOut will never be executed
    if ($("#fader").children().length > 0) {
        $("#fader").children().fadeOut(2000, DoFade);
    }
    else DoFade();
}

function DoFade() {
    // clone the object rather than move it so you can use it again.
    var $clone = $("#fadercontent").children().eq(index).clone().hide();

    $("#fader").html($clone);
    // fade in
    $("#fader").children().fadeIn(2000, function() {        
        FadeNext();
    });
}
```

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Jruns/2/

Comment: This forums is fab!!! Awesome! that did it! If I were to build in a delay/pause while showing the image/div content. Would that require an extra function or can I chain that somehow? Marking correct answer anyways. :o)

Comment: yeah, you could chain that pretty easily with `.delay(2000)`

Comment: after fadeIn().delay(2000) or?